# lidR - Bad scan angle

Tags: las, lidr

When reading a las file I'm getting the following error:

```
> readLAS("/tmp/chunk89/u_6300085100_2015.las")
Error: Invalid data: ScanAngle greater than -180 degrees.
In addition: Warning messages:
1: There are 1091 points flagged 'withheld'. 
2: There are 1091 points flagged 'synthetic'.
```

Is there anything that can be done to fix this?

Comment: What is the source of the point cloud. TLS?

Comment: No it is ALS, which implies that the scan angle greater than -180 degrees is wrong.

Comment: Be careful you may have a corrupted file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When reading a `las` file, the content is tested to check if the LAS specifications are respected. You found a case were the verification is a little bit too strict. Scan angle below -180 can be stored up to ±196.608 but are incorrect. You should have a warning instead of an error. This will be improved in `rlas`. See [this issue](https://github.com/Jean-Romain/rlas/issues/44).

That being said, here some options as workaround

#### Do not read the scan angle

```
readLAS("u_6300085100_2015.las", select = "* -a")
```

While this will solve most of the use cases this won't solve some specific cases such as the use of `lasnormalize()` with a `LAScatalog` because all the attributes are loaded. It assumes you do not need the scan angle.

#### Filter the invalid angles

Just skip the invalid data at read time

```
readLAS("u_6300085100_2015.las", filter = "-keep_scan_angle -180 180")
```

This should work with a `LAScatalog` as well

```
opt_filter(ctg) <- "-keep_scan_angle -180 180"
```

It assumes that the bad data correspond only to few weird outliers

#### Build a LAS object from raw data

You can bypass the use of `readLAS()`. But this option won't work with a `LAScatalog`

```
data <- rlas::read.las("u_6300085100_2015.las")
header <- rlas::read.lasheader("u_6300085100_2015.las")
las <- LAS(data, header, check = FALSE)
```